# Binding dropdownlist in 3-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm fairly new to 3-tier architecture and would love some help. I've tried to bind my dropdownlist with a single column in my database to no luck. Been reading alot on stackoverflow and other sites to no luck.

DAL:

```
public List<Product> getCatNameList()
    {
        var db = new Database();

        List<Product> CatNameList = db.Products.Select(p => new Product()
        {
            categoryname = p.ProductCategories.Name
        }).ToList();

        return CatNameList;
    }
```

BLL:

```
public List<Product> getCatNameList()
    {
        var ProductDAL = new ProductDAL();
        List<Product> allCatNames = ProductDAL.getCatNameList();
        return ProductDAL.getCatNameList();
    }
```

ProductController:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct()
    {
        var db = new ProductBLL();
        ViewBag.CatNames = new SelectList(db.getCatNameList(), "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.categoryname, new SelectList(ViewBag.CatNames, "Name")
```

The dropdownlist get populated with "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"'s. What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: It need to be `new SelectList(db.getCatNameList(), "Name", "Name:);` and  in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.categoryname, (SelectList)ViewBag.CatNames)`.

Comment: But why on earth does `getCatNameList()` create a new `Product` from each existing `Product`? And since you only seem to want the `ProductCategories.Name` property which is type of `string`, your method should be just `List<string> getCatNameList()`

Comment: Your first edit made the dropdown show "Model.Product" instead.

When it comes to your 2nd edit, I see what you mean. But how will the method look like when making it List<string> getCatNameList()?

Comment: Because none of your makes any sense at all. It would work if you use `Product.Name` instead of `Name` (in both cases) but as I noted you should be returning `List<string>`, not `List<product>`. And of course this will include duplicates.

Comment: Its not even clear why you would even need to repeat the method in both `DAL` and `BLL`. You should have just one method (in `DAL`) which returns `ProductCategory`, not `Product` (assuming you have a table named `ProductCategories`)

Comment: All you really need is `var categoryNames = db.ProductCategories.Select(c => c.Name); ViewBag.CatNames = new SelectList(categoryNames)` in the controller.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to get it working.

I set getCatNameList as a "public IQueryable<string>" and returned the categoryNames. And then used var categoryNames = db.getCatNameList(); ViewBag.CatNames = new SelectList(categoryNames); in the controller.